# Terminal git:master after oh-my-zshell installation

Tags: terminal, git, zsh

I just installed oh-my-zshell.
And my terminal looks like the image now. What is git master there?
I installed oh-my-zshell on other macs, the look is not like that. 
I am on the root here BTW.

Can you explain this, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically some of the oh-my-zsh themes provide special prompts for directories that are Git repositories. The 'git master' just means that it thinks that the directory you're in right now is a Git repository, with new, unstaged changes. All of this has to do with source control. I don't know your background with source control but you can look it up if you're curious.

I would start with looking at your ~/.zshrc file and see what ZSH_THEME is set to. Then, I would look inside ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/ and look for the theme that's set in ~/.zshrc. This latter typically has the prompt set that you're seeing right now. After this I'd change the prompt to look the way you want. In your case you might just want to disable the Git-related stuff from the place where the prompt is setting those variables.

Good luck!

Comment: I am experimenting both git and Terminal. Thanks for explanation. I have .git .gitconfig files. I must have started some of them while doing staff. What files can i delete in that root? Do you have any idea?

Comment: I moved .git file somewhere else and bumm. It is ok now. Thanks for enlightening.

Comment: Have a look at oh-my-zsh's plugin page. Git is only one of the plugins that comes by default. There are many others that are useful for almost any task. Now that your a Z-shell user, make the most out of it! ;)

Comment: I just installed prezto but problems occurred. Back to oh-my-zshrc. I should use this before switching. I am not at the place to judge the difference anyway. Thanks.